# What is wrong in the sentence "Servi si nasce, noi lo nacquimo"?

Tags: grammar, proverbs

Why is it wrong to write 'Servi si nasce, noi lo nacquimo'?

Comment: The form "nacquimo" is ironic, intentionally incorrect. Do not use it if you don't know what you are saying :-) My opinion is that this form tries to imitate Totò's famous sentence "signori si nasce e io modestamente lo nacqui".

Comment: In this [web site](http://www.antoniodecurtis.net/toto-signori-si-nasce-1960/) you can watch the film where this sentence comes from. Look at the minute 8:40.

Answer (score 8):

The sentence is an adaptation of Totò's famous sentence

> *«signori si nasce; e io modestamente lo nacqui»*

which could be roughly translated as

> *«noblemen are such by birth alone; and I, if you allow me to say so, was born such»*.

Totò's sentence has an exhilarating comic effect in Italian because it is pointlessly pompous, aristocratic; from a grammatical point of view it is correct, but totally inappropriate, extravagant. It is an authentic flash of genius. Grammatically, ["lo nacqui"](http://www.sapere.it/enciclopedia/lo+(pronome).html) means "I was born that" and, although it is correct, nobody would ever use it in everyday Italian, it would sound ridiculous. As suggested by Charo, you can watch the gag [here](http://www.antoniodecurtis.net/toto-signori-si-nasce-1960/) at minute 8:40.

The adaptation

> *«servi si nasce, noi lo nacquimo»*

is grammatically incorrect because, as pointed out by Josh61, the plural second person simple past of *"nascere"* is *"nascemmo"*, not *"nacquimo"*. The intentional error has an ironic effect, which is consistent with the meaning of the sentence, which could be roughly translated as

> *«servants are by birth, and we were **beared** such»* (*beared* instead of *born*)

Answer (score 3):

*Servi si nasce, noi lo nascemmo* is the correct sentence.

Passato Remoto di Nascere:

> io nacqui
>
> tu nascesti
>
> egli nacque
>
> *noi nascemmo*
>
> voi nasceste
>
> essi nacquero

Comment: However, for instance in a comedic context the sentence is absolutely acceptable, as a reference to Totò.

Comment: "lo nascemmo" sounds so wrong, "vi nascemmo" is the correct form.

Comment: lo (pronome)
- che si usa come compl. oggetto riferito a persona o cosa o anche con valore neutro (= ciò), in posizione sia proclitica sia enclitica: lo conosco bene; ridammelo subito!; non posso vederlo; non devi dirlo anche se lo pensi; lei non l'ama più. Spesso usato pleonasticamente: A) con valore predicativo in unione col verbo essere: ambiziosi lo siamo un po' tutti; si crede bella, ma non lo è. B) Con valore rafforzativo del compl. oggetto o di una proposizione oggettiva: non lo vedo l'albero; lo so che non è vero.

Comment: Giusto, @Josh61, ma che cosa stai citando?

Comment: Corretta l'[osservazione](http://www.sapere.it/enciclopedia/lo+(pronome).html) di Josh61. "Lo nacqui" significa "nacqui tale" e ovviamente non si userebbe mai nel linguaggio di tutti i giorni. Ma il lavoro del comico è anche questo: l'espressione suona inutilmente pomposa, aristocratica, grammaticalmente corretta ma totalmente inappropriata, stravagante, e quindi esilarante, un colpo di genio. Nota che "vi nacqui" sarebbe sbagliato (!) perché significherebbe "nacqui lì" e non "nacqui tale".